# How do I get more space and get my memory card to start working?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, insufficient-memory

I have a Galaxy S2 and it keeps saying "low on space" (phone storage is getting low) in my notifications. I bought a memory card and it still says low disk space so I can't download any apps. Also my Play Store app won't open. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The "low on space" message always refers to the device's internal memory. I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question; please see [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first-aid and helpful links. Don't forget to come back and either [edit] your question to specify where you got stuck, or answer it when you were able to solve your issue. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with Samsung Galaxy Ace 2. To make your default storage the sd card you need to modify vold.fstab. But to modify this file you need to root your phone.
I think there is no other way to do this.

Hope I have helped =).